# How can I replace a line with a new line in a txt file using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need a bit of help

I have a script that I can't make work, and I did try rewriting it different ways

this is my script

```
@echo off
set "Find="code1": 123456789,"
set "Replace="code1": 9999999999,"

set "source=File.txt"
set "target=result.txt"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %source%') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      if defined line set "line=!line:%Find%=%Replace%!"
      echo(!line!
   )
) > %target%
endlocal
```

This works great but only if I have an exact match 
`set "Find="code1": 123456789,"`

What I would like is for `Find` to only search by `code name` 
`set "Find="code1":"` or `"\"code1"\"` or `set "Find="code1":*"`

the reason is because each `file.txt` have different `values` for each `code` that I will look up. The `Replace value` will be the same for every `file.txt` I will work on, and each `file.txt` can have up to 15 codes for `Find`

This is my goal I want to replace the whole line where `code 1` is found with a new line or at least replace anything after `:`  and before `,`

Here is a partial of my content

```
file.txt - all these codes will always be different in every txt file
so the `Find` needs to search like a wildcard 
---content inside the file

  "fgrh": 442304728, < --- Code1
  "fdhe": 93075936,
  "rpsp": 0,
  "pcbp": 0.0,
  "dgcb": 117518,
  "dsds": 38785,
  "iags": 0,
  "yhgv": 180035,
  "ijnh": 51650,
  "igbk": 0,
  "ncde": 22935,
  "jnhy": 7450,
  "igsk": 0,
  "oihs": 1492,
  "ygbj": 60,
  "iggk": 0,
```

```
New Codes to replace old codes
all these codes will always remain the same for every file I work on

RESULTS
  "fgrh": 1251472, < --- Code1
  "fdhe": 12542,
  "rpsp": 0,
  "pcbp": 0.0,
  "dgcb": 52142,
  "dsds": 1342,
  "iags": 0,
  "yhgv": 14755,
  "ijnh": 4258,
  "igbk": 0,
  "ncde": 85411,
  "jnhy": 3581,
  "igsk": 0,
  "oihs": 200,
  "ygbj": 10,
  "iggk": 0,
```

Could a script be made like this PLEASE NOTE this lower script is just an example I put `< --- Code` just to show why I was using code1, code2, etc this `< ---- code is not apart of the script`

```
@echo off
   
   set "find="

  "fgrh": *, < --- Code1
  "fdhe": *, < --- Code2
  "rpsp": 0,
  "pcbp": 0.0,
  "dgcb": *, < --- Code3
  "dsds": *, < --- Code4
  "iags": 0,
  "yhgv": *, < --- Code5
  "ijnh": *, < --- Code6
  "igbk": 0,
  "ncde": *, < --- Code7
  "jnhy": *, < --- Code8
  "igsk": 0,
  "oihs": *, < --- Code9
  "ygbj": *, < --- Code10
  "iggk": 0,

    set "replace="
  "fgrh": 1251472, < --- Code1
  "fdhe": 12542, < --- Code2
  "rpsp": 0,
  "pcbp": 0.0,
  "dgcb": 52142, < --- Code3
  "dsds": 1342, < --- Code4
  "iags": 0,
  "yhgv": 14755, < --- Code5
  "ijnh": 4258, < --- Code6
  "igbk": 0,
  "ncde": 85411, < --- Code7
  "jnhy": 3581, < --- Code8
  "igsk": 0,
  "oihs": 200, < --- Code9
  "ygbj": 10, < --- Code10
  "iggk": 0,

    set "source=File.txt"
    set "target=result.txt"
    
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    (
       for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %source%') do (
          set "line=%%b"
          if defined line set "line=!line:%Find%=%Replace%!"
          echo(!line!
       )
    ) > %target%
    endlocal
```

I would also like to remove the %target% and make it edit the current file.txt 
I have an idea by doing this

```
 ) > %target% to  ) >> %source%
```

Not sure if anything else is needed to remove the target

Any help will be great

Comment: Can we assume, it's not literally `code<number>` but different strings? Are there other lines with the same formatting (`"something": 000000000`) which should not be changed?

Comment: this is the layout `"something": 00000000,` all codes have their own name, and every code will end with numbers, and the code can be anything from 4 letters to 6 letters, and every line has their own `"something":` so if I look for `"case": ` it will only find that one code, the word `case` might be found in data like this `"dsfg": all have a case`, but if the `find` is setup like this `"case": ` it will not see the other words - so not to worry about repeat codes found in the txt file

Comment: @Stephan - the codes I will be using will not affect other codes, for the codes only exist once in the file - that is why I put code1, code 2, code3 - I have like 15 codes that I would like to update and they are all non repeated codes and as long as we use this format `"something":` their will be no mistakes - Thank you for you time

Comment: You are trying to replace sub-strings per line (by `!line:%replace%=%replaced%!`, whereas variable `replaced` is never defined), but this is not what you want, since you want to replace whole lines, right? (To edit the original file, simply move the resulting file onto the original one using `move /Y "%target%" "%source%"`…)

Comment: @aschipfl - Yes, I started with replacing just the codes for another project and now I am trying to figure out how to replace the whole line example original line `"sdfg": 1245,` now the new line `"sdfg": 9999,` - almost every line ends with this `,`, a few lines does not have the `,`, but the most of all the codes I will be replacing will end with `,`

Comment: these should be much easier to do in powershell

Comment: @phuclv - yes I agree but I have no idea how to even get started with that - I'm learn batch right now and I'm getting the hand of it, but some projects do require more work like this one - everything I have is based on batch and I use this `CHOICE /c 123456789 /N /M "Type your choise"` and it's a batch format - I'm trying to add this script to this menu - not sure if I can add powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: (Complete rework according to various game-changing comments)

It isn't batch, which is too weak to handle the problem, it's your question that's too weak to be answered. It's more than frustrating to tailor a solution according to a question, just to be commented like "Nice, but doesn't work, because the facts are different than described in the question". You will have a much better response here, when you describe your *exact* problem, and not some "dummy facts".

**File.txt**

```
  "fgrh": 442304728, < --- Code1
  "fdhe": 93075936,
  "rpsp": 0,
  "pcbp": 0.0,
  "dgcb": 117518,
  "dsds": 38785,
  "iags": 0,
  "yhgv": 180035,
  "ijnh": 51650,
  "igbk": 0,
  "ncde": 22935,
  "jnhy": 7450,
  "igsk": 0,
  "oihs": 1492,
  "ygbj": 60,
  "iggk": 0,
```

**Replacements.txt**

```
  "fgrh": 1251472, < --- Code1
  "fdhe": 12542, < --- Code2
  "rpsp": 0,
  "pcbp": 0.0,
  "dgcb": 52142, < --- Code3
  "dsds": 1342, < --- Code4
  "iags": 0,
  "yhgv": 14755, < --- Code5
  "ijnh": 4258, < --- Code6
  "igbk": 0,
  "ncde": 85411, < --- Code7
  "jnhy": 3581, < --- Code8
  "igsk": 0,
  "oihs": 200, < --- Code9
  "ygbj": 10, < --- Code10
  "iggk": 0,
```

or

```
  "fgrh": 1251472, < --- Code1
  "fdhe": 12542, < --- Code2
  "dgcb": 52142, < --- Code3
  "dsds": 1342, < --- Code4
  "yhgv": 14755, < --- Code5
  "ijnh": 4258, < --- Code6
  "ncde": 85411, < --- Code7
  "jnhy": 3581, < --- Code8
  "oihs": 200, < --- Code9
  "ygbj": 10, < --- Code10
```

**Script.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "source=File.txt"
set "target=result.txt"
set "replacements=replacements.txt"
copy  /Y "%source%" "%target%" >nul
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=: " %%a in ("%replacements%") do (
  call jrepl "\q%%a\q.*" "\q%%a\q: %%b" /XSEQ /f "%target%" /o -
)
goto :eof
```

**Result.txt** (same with both versions of `replacements.txt`)

```
  "fgrh": 1251472, < --- Code1
  "fdhe": 12542, < --- Code2
  "rpsp": 0,
  "pcbp": 0.0,
  "dgcb": 52142, < --- Code3
  "dsds": 1342, < --- Code4
  "iags": 0,
  "yhgv": 14755, < --- Code5
  "ijnh": 4258, < --- Code6
  "igbk": 0,
  "ncde": 85411, < --- Code7
  "jnhy": 3581, < --- Code8
  "igsk": 0,
  "oihs": 200, < --- Code9
  "ygbj": 10, < --- Code10
  "iggk": 0,
```

I'm using [jrepl.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) because of its full REGEX capabilities, which makes life much easier.

The complete documentation for `jrepl.bat` is built-in and can be read with `jrepl /?` or more verbose `jrepl/??`

Comment: Thank you and my apologies about not knowing how the document looks, it is very large and sorry about the 999999 that was just an example, the results will have different numbers, I was aiming for a find and replace where it finds a code and replaces that line with a new line, that is why I put 99999 on all results, , also it works with 1 code, I tried with 2, and 5 codes and none change, when I added 1 code it changed, so it's good for 1 code, now if I make 15 scripts and make them `call` each other every code will get updated

Comment: looks like batch is to weak to handle this job - on the main file.txt it doesn't work, but if I extract the data and make the file smaller the script works - but this did help me with other projects - I was researching python and I can't find anything on how to replace a whole line, like your code, all I find is how to replace words crazy - Will you be able to make your answer read `*.txt`

Comment: I have updated my question using a small partial copy of my content - I hope this helps

Comment: Updated my answer a last time, using the file contents as stated in your updated question. (just minor changes to the code itself)

Comment: Thank you - this is driving me nuts - I know you got it to work, but for some reason I can't all it does is copies the file.txt to results.txt exactly the same - I even tested with the partial, and nothing - I did name the batch file to `jrepl.bat` and tried other names to see if that mattered, I even tried with the spaced in front of the codes and removed them - wow I'm going crazy here, I have file.txt, results.txt and replacement.txt all in the same folder and I run the script - I don't understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: Are you aware that you are supposed to download `jrepl.bat`, not rename this script to this name? Put it in the same folder as your script, or call it with it's full path.

Comment: OMG!!! - hahah nope had no idea - OK Got it, it works, Now I know - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following script should – as per my understanding – do what you want:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~dp0file.txt" & rem // (path to file to be edited; `%~dp0` is script parent)
set "_CODE=%~dp0code.txt" & rem // (path to file containing new codes to become applied)
set "_TMPF=%~dp0file.tmp" & rem // (path to temporary file)

rem // Write to temporary file:
> "%_TMPF%" (
    rem // Loop through lines of file, each one preceded with line number plus `:`:
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%_FILE%"') do (
        rem // Store current line (including line number prefix):
        set "LINE=%%L"
        rem // Try to extract text portion between prefix and next `:`:
        for /F "tokens=2 delims=: " %%K in ("%%L") do (
            rem // Check whether text portion is `"` plus anything plus `"`:
            cmd /V /D /C echo(!LINE:*:^=!| findstr "^ *\"[^^^":][^^^":]*\"" > nul && (
                rem // Text portion complies with pattern, hence store such:
                set "CODE=%%K"
                rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid troubles with `!` and `^`:
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                rem // Escape most `findstr` meta-characters (`*` it not handled!):
                for %%J in ("\" "." "^" "$" "[" "]" ""^") do set "CODE=!CODE:%%~J=\%%~J!"
                rem // Return line beginning with same text portion from other file:
                findstr /R /C:"^^ *!CODE!:" "!_CODE!" || echo(!LINE:*:=!
                endlocal
            ) || (
                rem // Text portion does not comply, hence return original line:
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                echo(!LINE:*:=!
                endlocal
            )
        )
    )
)
rem // Replace original file:
move /Y "%_TMPF%" "%_FILE%" > nul

endlocal
exit /B
```

You need to specify some file paths on top of the script:

- variable `_FILE` must point to the file containing the original codes:

  > ```cmd
  > "code1": 123456789,
  > "code2": 123123123,
  > "code3": 456456456,
  > ```
- variable `_CODE` must point to the file containing the new codes to use:

  > ```cmd
  > "code1": 9999999,
  > "code2": 9999999,
  > "code3": 9999999,
  > ```
- variable `_TMPF` just points to a temporary file;

---

If you want to apply this to multiple files, you should:

1. change the `rem // Define constants here:` section to:

   ```cmd
    rem // Define constants here:
    set "_FILE=%~1" & rem // (path to file to be edited; `%~1` is first argument)
    set "_CODE=%~2" & rem // (path to file containing new codes to become applied)
    set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (path to temporary file)
   ```
2. store the script, say as `replace-codes.bat`;
3. call the script in a loop:

- from Command Prompt:

  ```cmd
  for %I in ("*.txt") do call replace-codes.bat "%~I" "code.txt"
  ```
- from another batch file:

  ```cmd
  for %%I in ("*.txt") do call replace-codes.bat "%%~I" "code.txt"
  ```

Comment: I tried your script and I can't get it to work - I do understand how to set the `%~dp0` but something is not working - all it does is copy the original to the target folder, I know we can do this `set "_FILE=file.txt"` or this `set "_FILE=%~dp0Code Folder\file.txt"` can you double check your script - I made folders for all three locations placed the files in their folders and I do see it working, but nothing changes

Comment: You should specify full paths to all of the files; `set "_FILE=file.txt"` might point to a different location than you think, so better specify `set "_FILE=D:\path\to\file.txt"`…

Comment: I added full path to all 3 `set "_FILE=` `set "_CODE=` `set "_TMPF=` or should I only do file - Full paths to all 3 did not do anything same results - I will try to update my question better

Comment: Well, I tested my script and it worked, based on your sample data. Do the files contain any leading white-spaces in front of `"code?"`?

Comment: Before the code yes at least anywhere from 2 to 3 spaces - `|  "code1": 123456789,"`

Comment: I see the problem it's the spaces in front of the of `"code1":` each code has random spaces, so I'm assuming we need to add something for this - I have been researching how to fix the spacing, but can't find anything on that - can you tell me where to fix this

Comment: See my edit, which accounts for leading spaces…

Comment: I see all the changes you made, and it does work, but it also fails - for some odd reason it changes other codes in the file - well it doesn't look like batch can support the size of this file - do you know python?

Comment: As long as the files are less than 2 GiB in size, everything should be fine. For better debugging you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70701219/edit) your question and provide excerpts of true data files…

Comment: the file has a lot of content - I can share a portion on how the file looks, but I can't share the whole file - when I use my script if I match `Find` it works great with super speed - but I have to match it - when I ran your script on a partial txt file it worked and failed, it replaced all codes, but doubled other codes - but when I tried to run it on the original file the cmd just stated opened for a long time - like if it didn't have enough memory to run the job - I will update my question again - Thank you

Comment: I have updated my question using a small partial copy of my content hope this helps - am really trying to keep the replacement data in side the script because I am trying to add it to my batch menu I use this `CHOICE /c 123456789 /N /M "Type your choise` so I am really trying to add the the script and the codes with in the same .bat file, the replacement txt file I feel will be safer in the script then next to it, it might get deleted in the long run - I will always have a backup of course but the script will be used by many coworkers

Comment: Is it possible to make your script read `*.txt` I have tried changing some settings in it, but was not able to make it work

Comment: Also I was given 2 answers and both work in their own way, and I would like to check both as good, but I can't, not sure if that matters to you or not, but if it does I could ask a new question and you could answer there so I can check mark it - if you want

Comment: No, please don't post another similar question; it is totally your decision what answer you mark as accepted, you don't have to justify; once you've earned enough reputation you can up-vote all answers you find helpful; but thanks anyway!

Comment: Sure thing, I like to to give my respects and thanks to those that help me, I really do appreciate the help, being a beginner at this, I struggle a lot with making big projects codes work.. Will you be able to help me with making your script read `*.txt` @ASchipfl

Comment: See my last edit (at the bottom)…

Comment: Question is this needed in the path `%~1` and I'm, 
trying to figure out how to add a path `set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp"`
I tried different ways. 
.
I am using this `for %%I in ("*.txt") do call "%%~I" "code.txt"` 
So this script will be in it's own `.bat`files is that right, and I should rename
this script to `replace-codes.bat` So I will have 2 scripts is that right, if yes
I have named them like this main `script.bat` and `replace-codes.bat`
.
so the `script.bat` suppose to call or read from `replace-codes.bat` or the other way around..

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot to add the script itself to the `call` command lines (it wouldn't make sense to call a text file, would it?) – see again my latest edit…

Comment: No worries, now I got it to connect with the other batch, but I believe this section is my problem `set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp"` because it copies filename.tmp in the `_TMPF path` when I run the script it does nothing to the files, I gave these path  `FILE=New folder 1`  -  `CODE=New folder 3`  -  `TMPF=New folder 2`  - not sure what to with  `TMPF`  is it suppose to be like this `=New folder 2\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp`

Comment: Well, `set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp"` just defines the path to a temporary file, which you do not need to care about, it will be removed once the whole processing of the script is done…

Comment: OK, Understood but I can't get it to work, based on the move command `_file` needs to be in a folder and when I run the script, all that happens is the tmp files get moved to _file and the coding fails, I have tried for 3 hours to try to make this work, but no luck, the original scripts works great on a matching name like `file.txt` but does not work on the main file, my original request was for a file that has 588,000 lines, so your original script works but on smaller files, and I am using that on other projects, this project needs the `*.txt` do to the file names being different

Comment: Thank you for the hard work you put into this